# Can't validate form to send email

Tags: javascript, html

My form won't email and I think i'm missing if/elseif and return statements but not sure where to insert it

Trying to figure out where to insert return true/false statement into the code and code really use some help for this as i'm still a beginner to java script/ web development

```
  var message, x, j;
  message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML == "";
  x = document.getElementById("Firstname").value;
  try {

        if(x == "")  throw "Required Field";
        if (x = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/) throw "";
        if (x = /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/) throw "Invalid Characters Present";
        if (x = Number(x)) throw "Invalid Characters Present";
  }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = err;
  } 
}
```

thats the first function up above that validates the first input

```
function myFunction2() {
  var message, x, j;
  message = document.getElementById("message2");
  message.innerHTML == "";
  x = document.getElementById("Lastname").value;
  try {
        if(x == "")  throw "Required Field";
        if (x = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/) throw "";
        if (x = /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/) throw "Invalid Characters Present";
        if (x = Number(x)) throw "Invalid Characters Present";
  }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = err;
  }
}


function myFunction3  (){
  let message, x, j; //using let stops other functions from accidentally using it
   let RegExp = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; //pattern for email
   message = document.getElementById("message3"); //getting the error element
   message.innerHTML == ""; //declaring default value
   x = document.getElementById("Email").value; //x equals the email value

try{ //trying the conditions
   if (x === '') throw "Required Field"; //if x is blank then throw and error message
   else if (RegExp.test(x)) throw ''; //if the regexp testing pattern is valid then throw null
   else throw "Invalid Email Address"; //otherwise throw value is not valid
 }
 catch(err) { //this cathces the throw and produces the error message
   message.innerHTML = err;
 }
}



function myFunction4() {
  var message, x, j;
  message = document.getElementById("message4");
  message.innerHTML == "";
  x = document.getElementById("Subject").value;
  try {

    if(x == "")  throw "Required Field";
    if (x = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/) throw "";
  }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = err;
  }
}

function myFunction5() {
  var message, x, j;
  message = document.getElementById("message5");
  message.innerHTML == "";
  x = document.getElementById("Message").value;
  try {
    if(x == "")  throw "Required Field";
  if (x = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/) throw "";

  }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can see if your regex if statements need to be formatted correctly.

See [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/expressions-javascript/)

e.g.

```
var phoneRE = /^\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$/; 
  if (phoneNo.match(phoneRE)) {
    return true; 
  } else {
    alert( "The phone number entered is invalid!" );
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: the only issue i have with that is per our assignment we need to have a "message" which is a span element that becomes visible when the condition is met which is why i'm doing a throw catch rather then an alert